# AppleScript: move files with System Events or bash

Tags: bash, shell, automation, applescript

When using Finder, script can take a lot of time. I also want this script to work on the background. How can I use System Events/bash instead of Finder in this script?

```
property source_folder_one : alias "OS X:Users:username:Pictures:Work:New:one"
property source_folder_two : alias "OS X:Users:username:Pictures:Work:New:two"
property save_folder_one : alias "OS X:Users:username:Pictures:Work:Waitlist:one"
property save_folder_two : alias "OS X:Users:username:Pictures:Work:Waitlist:two"

tell application "Finder"
    move entire contents of folder source_folder_one to folder save_folder_one
    move entire contents of folder source_folder_two to folder save_folder_two
end tell

display notification "All images were relocated." with title "Relocating Complete" sound name "Glass.aiff"
tell me to quit
```

Comment: AppleScript doesn't support using multiple threads and isn't really a good choice for background tasks, etc. It's quite easy do this with a couple lines of code in bash, and then save it as a .command.

Comment: Use a do shell script command with unix command 'mv' to move all your files (using files with name *.* from folder A to folder B). It is done in background and at shell level (the fastest way).

Comment: Could you help me do that? I never wrote anything on bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made an applescript which does what you want.
But for one folder instead of two, you can choose the folder in an prompt.

```
set sourceFolder to (choose folder) as alias
set saveFolder to (choose folder) as alias
set sourceFolderPOSIXPath to (the POSIX path of sourceFolder)
set saveFolderPOSIXPath to (the POSIX path of saveFolder)

set shellString to "mv " & sourceFolderPOSIXPath & "* " & saveFolderPOSIXPath
do shell script shellString

display notification "All files were relocated." with title "Relocating Complete" sound name "Glass.aiff"
```

If you want to use your constant alias, just replace `(choose folder)` with `"OS X:Users:username:Pictures:Work:New:one"` and so on.